# Powershell is writing ASCII Code instead of characters in Excel-File using COM-Object

Tags: excel, powershell, ascii

I have an Excel file with several tables. One table is my sample solution, the other is external work. In the sample solution there are several columns that are also present in the contributed table. However, the same columns are not always filled in in the added table. The goal is to write a Powershell script that recognizes which columns are filled in and writes them to the matching columns in the sample solution. What works so far. For this I created an array for each column in the sample solution, which is then filled with the matching values from the processed list.

`$Arrays = @($IDArray, $Array1, $Array2, $Array3, $Array4, $Array5, $Array6, $Array7, $Array8, $Array9, $Array10, $Array11, $Array12, $Array13)`

Then the script writes them into the sample solution. As mentioned, not all columns are always filled out in the processed list. If a column is not filled in, I fill the corresponding array with "-" so that they are transferred to the sample solution.

By debugging the script I also see that the arrays are filled correctly. Strangely, however, the ASCII value of the "-" (45) ends up in the Excel table. However, this only happens when I fill an array completely with "-". If only one value is missing in an existing column, then it fills it correctly with "-".

```
foreach ($array in $Arrays){
    $index = 0
    while ($index -ne $IDArray.Count) {
        try {
            if([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($array[$index])){
                $array[$index] = '-'
            }
            else {
                $array[$index] = "'" + $array[$index]
            }
        }
        catch {
            $array = $array + '-'   
        }
        finally{
            $index++
        }
    }

    $Arrays[$IndexArrays] = $array
    $IndexArrays++
    $array = @()
}
```

This is the Code for replacing or adding the "-" Value in my Arrays.

I fill in in the Excel file with this code:

```
$ArrayIndex2 = 0
$CounterSpalte = 1
$CounterZeile = 0
$ArrayIndex1 = 0

while ($CounterZeile -lt $IDArray.Count) {
    while($CounterSpalte -lt $j){
        $ExcelComObjectWorkSheetMuster.Cells.Item($IDIndexMuster + $CounterZeile, $CounterSpalte) = $Arrays[$ArrayIndex1][$ArrayIndex2]
        $ArrayIndex1++
        $CounterSpalte++
    }
    $ArrayIndex1 = 0
    $ArrayIndex2++
    $CounterZeile++
    $CounterSpalte = 1
}
```

After running the script, my Excel file looks like this:

[image]

"correct value" and "-" are correct. but somehow, 45 is also in there.

Comment: I recommend you to use [PSCustomObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject)s rather than (jagged) arrays in PowerShell as there is a general pitfall where single item arrays unroll in the contained item. Anyways, try using the [unary comma operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#comma-operator-): `$Arrays[$IndexArrays] = ,$array`

Comment: Besides, the initiator (`$array = @()`) should come prior the `while` loop otherwise the first array will be `$Null` (instead of an empty array) or taken from the parent scope.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].